# How to create an error (aka confusion) matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, confusion-matrix

How can I generate an error (aka confusion) matrix in R?

Let's start with some sample data:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,2,3,4,2,1,4,5,5,1)
b = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,2,3,4,2,2,4,5,2,1)
```

This is what I am aiming to achieve based on the sample data:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [total]
 [,1]  3    1                    4
 [,2]       4                    4
 [,3]            2               2
 [,4]                3           3
 [,5]       1              3     4
[total]3    6    2   3     3     16
```

I can create a simple cross tabulation matrix using `table()`, however I cannot seem to get the row, column and overall totals.

```
> table(a,b)
   b
a   1 2 3 4 5
  1 3 1 0 0 0
  2 0 4 0 0 0
  3 0 0 2 0 0
  4 0 0 0 3 0
  5 0 1 0 0 2
```

Comment: Look into `confusionMatrix()` in `library(caret)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get row, column, and overall totals, just use `addmargins`:

```
> addmargins(table(a, b))
     b
a      1  2  3  4  5 Sum
  1    3  1  0  0  0   4
  2    0  4  0  0  0   4
  3    0  0  2  0  0   2
  4    0  0  0  3  0   3
  5    0  1  0  0  2   3
  Sum  3  6  2  3  2  16
```

Comment: (+1) kewl... Never heard of that one

Comment: Hi @ananda-mahto could you help me in this question, I have similar case, but I want to implement kind of function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095286/how-to-create-r-output-likes-confusion-matrix-table thank you